# What is { } when passed to a function in CPP?

Tags: c++, stl, initialization, list-initialization

The `map` `insert` function takes `{string,int}` as argument. how does this work?

```
#include <map>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char *arg[])
{
    map<string, int> m;

    m.insert({"a", 1});
}
```

Comment: It's casted. Compiler knows the type of m, and for compiler {"a", 1} seems no problem to be a member of m.

Comment: If you are using an older compiler (or compiling to an older C++ standard), possibly it may not recognize the intent for a temporary object passed in.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`{"a", 1}` is a *braced-init-list*, and when being passed to a function, [copy-list-initialization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/list_initialization) (introduced in C++11) is performed.

> ```
> function( { arg1, arg2, ... } )   (7)
> ```
>
> 7) in a function call expression, with braced-init-list used as an
>   argument and list-initialization initializes the function parameter

Given `map<string, int> m;` and `m.insert({"a", 1});`, [`std::map::insert`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/insert) expectes a `std::pair<const string, int>`; therefore `{"a", 1}` is used to initialize a temporary `std::pair` which is passed to `.insert()`. The temporary `std::pair` is initialized by its [constructor](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/pair/pair); initializing its members `first` to `"a"` and `second` to `1`.